# How to change the color in the vegan graph? (bray)

Tags: r, vegan

Here is my code

```
library(vegan)
library(MASS)


row.names(Data) <- c("SI1", "SII0", "SI0", "SII2", "SI2", "SII1", "SIII0", "SIV2", "SIII2", "SIV1", "SIII1", "SIV0")
bcdist <- vegdist(Data, "bray")

bcmds <- isoMDS(bcdist, k = 2)


plot(bcmds$points, type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")

text(bcmds$points, dimnames(Data)[[1]])
```

Then I get this [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqlgB.jpg). How do I add colors for every point in the graph? Thank you

Here is my [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yoy3v6hae2m1782/bray1.xlsx?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify a colour for each point/group or use a pre-made colour pallet (must be at least as long as your number of groups):

```
cols <- c("red", "blue", "green"....etc)
```

Then include the col argument in the plotting function, choosing a label colour based on your row names:

```
text(bcmds$points, dimnames(Data)[[1]], col = cols)
```

Comment: ... and **absolutely** remember to use argument `asp = 1` in your `plot()`. It takes care of isometric scaling of your graph, and that is important in ordination plots (not the least as you are using **iso**MDS).

Comment: @David Foster Thank you for the quick reply but it didnt change the color. Still got the same graph

Comment: @David Foster here is my code >
cols <- c("red", "blue","blue", "green","green","red","blue","green","green","red","red","blue")

Comment: @MrGoodNews Please see above edit - if we're specifying colour of each case individually in order, then we don't need to choose based on rownames. Just use `col = cols`